# Matrix with horizontal nested group header setup

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, group-by, nested, tabular

I have to make a report that have to look like this:

[image: Desired Look]

Taking it from this query result, group by Program, Code:

[image: Query Result]

I managed to show it like this using a matrix:

[image: Current Undesired Result]

but that is not what I need.
I can't figure out how to put the horizontal header that expands across the whole table playing with the groups.
Can any one assist me in this specific case?